# cannot take the children count from the parent layout

Tags: android

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CustomAutoCompleteTextView cat;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name();

        cat = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.a_no);
        String[] from = { "NAME", "ID" };
        int[] to = { R.id.auto_id, R.id.auto_name };
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, values, R.layout.row, from,
                to);
        cat.setAdapter(adapter);
        cat.setThreshold(1);
        cat.setOnItemClickListener(autoItemSelectedListner);


    }


    private OnItemClickListener autoItemSelectedListner = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) arg0
                    .getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

             LinearLayout v1 = (LinearLayout) arg1.getParent();
             Log.i("tag",v1.getChildCount() +"");


        }

    };
```

**CustomAutoCompleteTextView**

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

        public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
        @Override
        protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {

            HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
            return hm.get("NAME");
        }
    }


        }
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="kasun" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="22sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="22sp" >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <com.example.autocomplete.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/a_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Account No" >
        </com.example.autocomplete.CustomAutoCompleteTextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

In the above example i try to populate some data  using custom auto complete .This code is working as i expected.But i need to count the children widgets in the parent layout when a value is slected from autocomplete.Here this parent layout is linear layout it contains 3 widget.(1 custom autocomplete and 2 Edit text).you can see it on the main_activity.xml. ut it gives the following error

```
05-21 10:34:01.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4118): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Comment: you probably need to getCount of your adapter

Comment: Log.i("count", arg0.getChildCount()+"");but it gives value 1 instead of 3

Comment: call getCount of your adapter, not getChildCount of arg0

Comment: Actually in my real example  i have 3 autocomplete and 2 Edit Text inside 1nside 3 linear layout.So i need to get the child count of layout corrosoponding  to the autocomplete .

Comment: i dont understand what you really need: do you want to know the number of items shown in your dropdown list?

Comment: No i need to count the no of widgets in the layout out.in this exaample it has 2 edit texts and 1 autocomplete.(see activity_main.xml)

Comment: so it it always 3, why to get it using getChildCount if it is always 3?

Comment: In my real example I create linear layout dynmically and each layout contains 2 edit text with 1 autcomplete.So when i select a value form autocomplete i need change the value write next to autocomplete.To do that i need to get the child count   and change the value of edit text next to the autocomplete

Comment: i still dont get it, so you have N elements, each one containing two EtitTexts and one AutoCompleteTextView, right?

Comment: co create a class implementing OnItemClickListener with 3 fileds: EditText et0; EditText et1; AutoCompleteTextView avtv; and call actv.setOnItemClickListene(this); in the constructor

Comment: can u elaborate the answer i m new to android

Comment: I posted detailed answer, is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Here arg1 view means your autocomplete textview and you write arg1.getParent() means you get CustomAutoCompleteTextView. then you Cast it to Linear layout so error generate. you have to write  arg1.getParent().getParent() then you get LinearLayout. Try it...

OR

Also you can just write arg0.getParent() then you get LinearLayout.

Comment: LinearLayout l= (LinearLayout) arg1.getParent().getParent() ;
  Log.i("xzxz", l.getChildCount()+" "); i add this still gives the following error
05-21 11:13:01.091: E/AndroidRuntime(5843): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: Have you try second suggestion?

Comment: Checking with that but no luck yet. I hope that will done it soon.

Answer (score 0):

The arg0 is the popupview in which you clicked an item. And arg1 is the specific item of the popupview in which you clicked. So that arg1.getParent() gives you the popupview. And arg0 gives you the popupView and you tried to convert that to linearlayout. So that you got ClassCastException.

**Update:**

```
There were no reference found in the onItemClickListener(). So I get the parent from the instance of autocomplettextview as,

ll = (LinearLayout) cat.getParent(); 
Log.i("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", ll.getChildCount() + "");
```

If you are creating the autocompletetextview, just use an array of linearlayout and add the autocompleteview in the linearlayout array.

Comment: ViewGroup v1= (ViewGroup) arg1.getParent().getParent().getParent();
   Log.i("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", v1.getChildCount()+"") ;
05-21 12:13:24.156: E/AndroidRuntime(10214): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: Try, 
 CustomAutoCompleteTextView cactv = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) arg1.getParent();
 LinearLayout v1 = (LinearLayout) cactv.getParent();

Comment: gives this error
05-21 13:01:10.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2850): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView cannot be cast to com.example.autocomplete.CustomAutoCompleteTextView

Comment: Ok let me check with mock project.

Comment: hey did u try the project

Comment: Im trying to download, but it din't. Can you send it to my mail?

Comment: plz send me ur mail.thnx for ur help

Comment: hey any luck with the mock project

Comment: There is no way to get the parent view from onItemClickListener().
I got it from the instance of the autocompletetextview,
ll = (LinearLayout) cat.getParent();
    Log.i("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", ll.getChildCount() + "");

Comment: If you adding the autocompletetextview dynamically, you can make an array of autocompletetextview and get the parent from the specific instance of autocompletetextview.

Comment: can u eloborate ur answer

Answer (score 0):

so if i understand you right, try this class:

```
class Row extends LinearLayout implements OnItemClickListener {

    private EditText et0;
    private EditText et1;
    private AutoCompleteTextView actv;

    public Row(Context context) {
        super(context);
        et0 = new EditText(context);
        et1 = new EditText(context);
        actv = new AutoCompleteTextView(context);
        actv.setHint("enter D...");
        actv.setThreshold(1);
        actv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        addView(et0, p);
        addView(et1, p);
        addView(actv, p);
        String[] columnNames = {BaseColumns._ID, "name0", "name1"};
        MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            c.newRow().add(i).add("DOG " + i).add("CAT " + i);
        }
        String[] from = {"name0"};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, c, from, to, 0);
        adapter.setStringConversionColumn(1);
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CursorAdapter a = (CursorAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        Cursor c = a.getCursor();
        et0.setText(c.getString(1));
        et1.setText(c.getString(2));
    }
}
```

the test code is as follows (add it in onCreate):

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ll.addView(new Row(this));
}
setContentView(ll);
```